# Typescript compiler hangs forever (tsc command)

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a pretty small typescript app (few files). Everything works and compiles locally. However, whenever I try to do it on my digital ocean droplet, the `tsc` script hangs forever.

I ran the build with `--verbose` flag and here’s the output. Does anyone know why the `tsc` command hang forever, or what I can do next to diagnose/fix the issue?

```
root@jcm-v2:/var/www/html/jcm-api-v2# npm run build --verbose
npm verb cli /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/npm
npm info using npm@8.18.0
npm info using node@v18.7.0
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 5ms
npm timing config:load:file:/usr/share/nodejs/npm/npmrc Completed in 7ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 7ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 5ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/var/www/html/jcm-api-v2/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 7ms
npm timing config:load:file:/root/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:file:/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 35ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 36ms
npm timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 2ms
npm verb title npm run build
npm verb argv "run" "build" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 4ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 7ms
npm timing npm:load:display Completed in 30ms
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/root/.npm/_logs
npm verb logfile /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-07T03_47_00_121Z-debug-0.log
npm timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 20ms
npm timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 101ms
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠼ : timing npm:load Completed in 101ms
> jcm-api@1.0.0 build
> tsc

npm timing command:run Completed in 2000263ms
npm verb exit 0
npm timing npm Completed in 2000414ms
npm info ok
```

FWIW, I started with Typescript version **4.6.4** which was hanging and I upgraded to version **4.9.5** and it's still hanging.

I uninstalled and re-installed Typescript several times and confirmed that the version matches my `package.json` version.

Locally, I'm on version **4.6.3** the application builds and compiles just fine.

## Update

I updated my local typescript version to **4.9.5** and it still compiles locally fine.

## Versions

- I'm running Ubuntu 22.10
- Node: v18.7.0
- NPM: 8.18.0
- Typescript: 4.9.5

Here's are my dependencies from package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.10.0",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.12.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  }
```

Comment: I don't have the expertise to answer this, but if anyone can then they'll need a lot more information about the system your are trying to run on. Sounds like there might be a low-level issue in the OS. To start, what version of Linux are you running? What version of node? What are your dependencies? Etc.

Comment: I updated the main description with the info below as well.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10
Node: v18.7.0
NPM: 8.18.0
Typescript: 4.9.5

Here's are my dependencies from package.json

  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.10.0",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.12.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  }

Comment: "--verbose" was definitely a good start.  You might also try `tsc  --verbose --diagnostics`, and compare the "good" vs. "bad" environments.

Comment: Yea, I tried `--diagnostics` before. It just hangs same as regular `tsc` command...

Comment: `root@jcm-v2:/var/www/html/jcm-api-v2# tsc --build --verbose --diagnostics
[4:24:49 AM] Projects in this build:
    * tsconfig.json

[4:24:49 AM] Project 'tsconfig.json' is out of date because output file 'dist/app.js' does not exist

[4:24:49 AM] Building project '/var/www/html/jcm-api-v2/tsconfig.json'...`
It hangs on that last line

Answer (score 2):

So the issue was that the system was running out memory. Adding a swap file fixed it.

FWIW, I followed these instructions for my digitial ocean droplet.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04